# Initialization logic of a Azure ARM solution template without VM resource

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Is it possible to have an ARM solution template (createUiDefinition.json, azuredeploy.json, etc) published to Azure Marketplace, which have an App Service and a CosmosDB account resources but does not has any VM resources to have initialization logic (e.g. creation of CosmosDB database, collections) which executes once solution template is deployed.

In case if solution template contained VM, then it would be possible to use a Custom Script Extension, but is there a way without VMs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you exactly after, but we are using Azure Function as a part of an arm template to configure cosmosDb. here is how it works:

```
"uri": "[concat('https://functionUrl?param1=', parameters('cosmosName'), '&param2=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', parameters('cosmosName')), '2016-03-31').primaryMasterKey, '&code=', parameters('functionKey'))]"
```

this will call Azure Function and give it the cosmosDb name and key and you can use that in your Azure Function to connect to cosmosDb and configure it. the only caveat  is your function should return empty template (or not empty, just parseable by the engine).

```
var template = @"{'$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#', 'contentVersion': '1.0.0.0', 'parameters': {}, 'variables': {}, 'resources': []}";
HttpResponseMessage myResponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
myResponse.Content = new StringContent(template, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return myResponse;
```

Comment: Is it possible to deploy that Azure Function within the same ARM solution template which contains cosmosDB account resource? 
If yes, then it solves my problem.

Comment: well, technically yes. you can use public github repo to define function code. also take a look here: https://gist.github.com/christopheranderson/ec6ab6b1eae152fca5321f4044b33d1d